# Determining the effect of number of likes

Tags: time-series, data-mining, predictive-models, interpretation

Let's say I have marketing data and I need to determine how effective the marketing is. The marketing strategy is to publish facebook posts at inconsistent intervals.

**The goal** is to see how the `number of likes` translates into `revenue`.

The data that I have is:

- Daily revenues (revenue vs time since a facebook `post`)
- Number of likes (with date)
- The weather (sunshine, cloudy, rainy/snowy, and daytime temperature)
- (derived) Season and day of the week

Most likely the relationship between `number of likes` and `revenue` will be non-linear and greatly depend on `weather` and the `day of the week`. Also, the `weather` is not independent of `season`. Finally, the effect of facebook posts is lagged, and potentially the lag varies significantly.

**Questions**

- Do I need to correct for growth of revenues over the years? If yes, how? (by finding a regression model, and then adjusting the values around it?)
- How would I find the average lag period between a `post` and a change in `revenue` "due" to that post?
- What models can I use to determine the effect of `likes`?

**Personal thoughts**

- ARIMA (not quite sure how it works)
- Regression trees. For example, if I wanted to see how the power (to increase revenue) of the `number of likes` is affected by the `weather`, I could make a plot of `likes` vs `weather` by:

  1. To find one point on that plot, keep `number of likes` and `weather` static.
  2. Iterate over all possible values of all other variables.
  3. Merge the predictions into one (the average or the median).
- Fourier analysis to determine the lag
- Would a Markov model work here? Or potentially conditional random fields?

Comment: Seems like you're interested in a causal effect of likes on revenue, yes?  Rather than a strictly predictive model?  If so, you need to consider whether `likes` is endogenous to revenue.  For example, `likes` presumably cause `revenue` to increase, but higher `revenue` could imply that the product is getting out into the population, which could affect the number of likes.  Strategies for addressing this probably exist with your data.

Comment: Do you know of any strategies for this purpose?

Comment: They fall under the broad heading of instrumental variables.  Some combination of lags could probably serve as instruments in your case, but I'd need to think about it further.  What temporal resolution does your data have?

Comment: It would definitely have daily, if not down to the minute (raw data that is)